# Can I use this aggregate for bedding for my patio?

Tags: patio

The aggregate shown below was salvaged from a shed that I removed from my backyard
I am planning to use it to correct the pitching of my patio (see my other questions in this forum for details)

Can I use this aggregate? It is pretty similar with what was used before when the patio was installed

bigger pictures here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKai9.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwbwG.jpg

Note: first picture shows a coarser aggregate
Second picture shows some traces of gravel. I can remove those, that is not a problem
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you have is *stone dust*, and it is what I used as the top 2.5" layer under my patios. It is perfect for making grade adjustments to the patio. Keep in mind under the 2.5" top layer there should be a 4 - 6" base of compactable gravel for best drainage.